# Browser can't access Virtual Machine development website in Windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant

Not sure what is going on here. Some months ago it worked and now it doesn't. I have a Windows 10 environment running a virtual machine for testing websites using Vagrant. The config in Vagrant is fine and sets up the IP address (192.168.33.10) as a private network. In the Windows Hosts file I have the development domain setup as well. For example:

192.168.33.10   test.dev

After 'vagrant up' all looks fine. A ping of both the IP and development domain works and a 'curl' of the development domain returns the correct html.

But when I put the development domain into a browser I immediately get an 'Unable to connect' error. The error comes instantly so it is getting to the server but then something is rejecting it.

Does anyone have any clues please?

Comment: can you check the nginx/apache logs on the vagrant machine?

Comment: I checked the access logs (there were 2 with data in them) /var/log/access.log showed the interaction with the IP address. /var/log/access.log.1 showed the interaction with the domain name but only showed data when it was working months ago - nothing new. I ran Fiddler to see if it could find anything and it returned a 502 error on the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the best part of a week trying all sorts of things I found the answer. The domain '.dev' is now a legitimate global domain and Firefox and Chrome now force anything 'name.dev' to HTTPS which then throws back an error that it can't connect.

See https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/